# Setting the date of a file to that of the previous month - KornShell

Tags: shell, ksh

Im trying to set up a KornShell script so a file is FTP'd on the first of each month.

When the file is created it should read the date of the previous month - If the job was ran on April 1st the file would be filename_MAR2023. Is this something that is included in the body of the script or would a variable need to be set up at the start?

Thank you in advance!

I have tried `` DATE=`date +%d%m%y` ``  as a variable but this seems to me like it would just take the current date and apply that in a numerical value.

Comment: `date +%Y-%b --date='-1 month'` gives `2003-Feb`. Getting an all-caps abbreviation will be your challenge (`tr` or `sed` can do it). ALSO, I highly recommend using ` date +%Y-%m --date='-1 month'` which gives `2023-02` as these dates naturally sort. Once you have more that one year's data, any time you do an `ls /myDated/Dir` all the same months will group together over multiple years, which will make programming any processing more complicated. Good luck!

Comment: (This solution works in any shell, as long as the `date` command supports the `--date='....'` option. Some don't or you are required to install something like gnu-date.)

Comment: When you can't install a GNU like `date`, you can also think about the `find` option `-ctime` or `-mtime`, which might be useful in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `printf`'s `%T` directive can parse a datetime string much like GNU's `date -d`

```bash
fname="my_filename"
typeset -u date=$(printf '%(%b%Y)T' 'last month')
newname="${fname}_${date}"
print -v newname
# => my_filename_APR2023
```

```bash
$ printf --man
NAME
  printf - write formatted output

SYNOPSIS
  printf [ options ] format [string ...]
...
    %T    Treat string as a date/time string and format it. The T can be preceded by (dformat),
          where dformat is a date format as defined by the date command.
```

This is:

```bash
$ print -v .sh.version
Version AJM 93u+ 2012-08-01
```